# Optimizing a loop

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am implementing an example given in the book The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction (Hashtle, Tibshirani, Friedman).

My aim is to generate 10+10 means from two bivariate normal distributions, then use the first ten means to generate points labelled "Green" and the other ten means to generate "Red" points. The mean value of the bivariate gaussian from which a point must be generated has to be picked randomly every time. I am not too familiar with R, so I used the for-loop, using which it takes an awful lot of time as n gets bigger. Here's my code:

```
Sigma = diag(2)
greenMeans= mvrnorm(n=10, c(1,0), Sigma)
redMeans= mvrnorm(n=10, c(0,1), Sigma)

n=1000000
green<- array(dim=c(n,2))
red<- array(dim=c(n,2))

for (i in 1:n)
        {
            newGreen<- mvrnorm(n=1,greenMeans[sample(c(1:10),1,replace=TRUE),], Sigma/5)
            newRed<- mvrnorm(n=1,redMeans[sample(c(1:10),1,replace=TRUE),], Sigma/5)
            green[i,1] <- newGreen[1]
            green[i,2] <- newGreen[2]
            red[i,1] <- newRed[1]
            red[i,2] <- newRed[2]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the for loop entirely and use `replicate`, not sure how much faster it is though:

```
do_stuff = function() {
   newGreen<- mvrnorm(n=1,greenMeans[sample(c(1:10),1,replace=TRUE),], Sigma/5)
   newRed<- mvrnorm(n=1,redMeans[sample(c(1:10),1,replace=TRUE),], Sigma/5)         
   return(list(newGreen, newRed))
 }
replicate(10000, do_stuff)
```

Comment: those two commands aren't equivalent,

`sample(redMeans, 1, replace = TRUE)`

doesn't take into account the fact that we have a two-dimensional array in our hands; it picks a random number from the 20 scalars in the vector. It should pick a random point from the vector redMeans.

Also, `mu` argument of `mvrnorm` doesn't work like that. `mu` is a vector giving the means of the variables, not the vector that contains the means for every single point.

Comment: @user2058602 I removed the wrong and speculative part of my answer.